# Check if string matches regex list of patterns in Python

Tags: python

How would I test if a string `June` tests True for any of the regex patterns in a given list, ignoring case sensitivity as well. I'm using python to do this.

```
['Ju*','October'] = True
['june','November'] = True
['*u*','October'] = True
['Junee','October'] = False
['October']` = False
['*'] = True
```

Comment: Can we see the code you wrote to try and solve this problem?

Comment: By the way, neither `*` nor `*u*` are valid regex patterns. You may be thinking of globbing.

Comment: Regex supports wildcards which is *

Comment: Regex does not have wildcards. The asterisk in regex is not a wildcard.

Comment: the regex wild card is not `*`, it is `.*`. (assuming no whitespace)

Comment: Well i guess how would i write code that would provide a solution for what im asking above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:

```
def doesMatchPattern(self, string, patterns=[]):
    for p in patterns:

        # skip empty patterns
        if not p: continue

        # construct regex pattern
        pattern = '^{}$'.format(p.lower())
        if '*' in pattern:
            pattern = pattern.replace('*', '[^\\s]*')

        if re.match(pattern, string, re.I):
            return True

    return False

print doesMatchPattern('june', ['Ju*'])
print doesMatchPattern('june', ['june'])
print doesMatchPattern('june', ['*u*'])
print doesMatchPattern('june', ['Junee'])
print doesMatchPattern('june', ['October'])
print doesMatchPattern('june', ['*'])
```

Comment: You know we can see you are answering yourself, you don't need to pretend to be someone giving you the answer :')

Comment: haha, i ended up figuring it out, it is only helpful that i share it with the community.

Comment: And you figured it out 2 hrs after you asked the question. You should have added this solution as part of your question so people can see what you tried doing and then checking if there is better option.